# How to automate scenario to verify if email is received by user after every 8 hour/daily/ once in a week in selenium ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, selenium

How to verify if user is receiving email after every 8 hours in a day or one email a day or once in a week in selenium ruby as per the option user selects for getting email notification.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that selenium is capable of. Selenium is used for functional testing from within the browser whereas email is generated out of [Rails mailers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) and doesn't interact with the views.

You can test the mailers using built in [mail testers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers). And to test the delay likely you'll need to use [Active Job](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) which you'll need to [test on their own](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-jobs) as well.